# Devo liberar toda a memória alocada ao terminar um programa?

Tags: c, c++, gerenciamento-de-memória, sistema-operacional

É comumente aceito que quando eu aloco um bloco de memória eu sou o responsável por liberar-lo. Isso é particularmente verdade quando programando baseado em RAII. No entanto o seguinte programa funciona perfeitamente:

```c++
int main() {
    int* ptr = new int[99999];
    return 0;
}
```

Aqui o sistema deve ser capaz de liberar tudo que o processo alocou.

O que é considerado boa prática aqui? Devo sempre liberar a memória que eu aloco? Há algum problema/vantagem em deixar esse trabalho para o sistema?

Comment: Se o Dollynho Programador diz que você pode deixar alocado sim quando o programa é encerrado, então é porque você TEM que desalocar quando o programa encerra XD

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Um ponto a se considerar é que código que hoje em dia é um programa completo pode eventualmente ser refatorado para se tornar uma funcionalidade de outro programa maior. Se o programa original não se preocupava em liberar os recursos (por que o SO ia fazer isso por ele), agora ele vai começar a gerar um *leak* no programa maior cada vez que sua funcionalidade for executada. Muitas horas de depuração vão ser perdidas até identificar a origem do problema, e mais ainda refatorando o código original para se comportar direito.

Comment: Essa é a resposta certa. Não é boa prática, mesmo que o SO te ajude a evitar problemas maiores. Em algum momento, você vai ter que resolver um vazamento de memória por isso.

Comment: Se o preço a pagar pela finalização rápida é a quebra de modularidade, é claramente caro demais. Esse ponto eu não havia levado em consideração.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Quando você mais de 4 GB alocados, talvez não ache que a quebra de modularidade seja cara demais.

Answer (score 8):

Não considero uma boa prática deixar o sistema liberar todos os recursos que foram alocados pelo programa. Devo lembrar que memória é apenas um dos recursos que o sistema deve gerenciar e se, o único recurso que o seu programa usa é somente memória, o que eu acho pouco provável em programas de médio ou grande porte, ainda assim, não considero uma boa prática.

A função `exit`, conforme resposta dada pelo próprio autor, deve ser utilizada com cautela e deve-se saber de seus efeitos colaterais. Um dos problemas de se utilizá-la é:

- Criação de múltiplos pontos de saída de um programa, o qual pode dificultar o debug;
- Pode dificultar a leitura de um programa, no fundo, equivale a múltiplos *goto* para o fim do programa;
- Não libera os recursos de forma clara e limpa.

Na verdade, chamo a atenção para o fato que chamar a função `exit` é diferente do que chamar a instrução `return` ao final do programa `main`. Enquanto a instrução `return` realiza o "desempilhamento do pilha (*unwind stack*)", o que permite chamar todos os destrutores do objetos locais, a função `exit` não o faz, o que pode causar erros de lógica, não facilmente detectáveis em um debug.

Chamo a atenção também que a ideia de deixar o SO cuidar de liberar os recursos só acontece em SOs "modernos". Em SOs, como os do tipo do FreeRTOS é de total resposabilidade do programador liberar os recursos alocados.

Novamente, volto a questão de que a memória é apenas uns dos recursos gerenciados. SOs modernos liberam todos os recursos alocados pelo programa, no fechamento do processo, não importando o estado em que se encontram (se tiver que fazer um flush num arquivo, para salvar os dados, isso não acontecerá no encerramento do processo). O autor, em sua resposta, sugere a criação de callbacks ou um sistema de mensagens para auxiliar o processo. Considero que isso apenas complica a lógica do sistema. Acho um preço muito baixo deixar o sistema fazer a destruição automática de todos os objetos de forma clara, limpa e segura, mesmo que isso acarrete retirar a memória do swap. E visualizando os sistemas de hardware atuais, onde memória é um recurso que pode ser considerado abundante, não justifica todas essa lógica a mais.

Comment: Como sempre, tudo tem o seu contexto. `memória é um recurso que pode ser considerado abundante` não é verdade para desenvolvimento embarcado, como em celulares. Ainda assim, concordo com todo o resto de sua resposta.

Answer (score 7):

Em qualquer sistema operacional moderno é utilizado o recurso de páginas virtuais de memória. Nesse modelo cada processo é dono de todo um espaço de endereçamento e o sistema tem a responsabilidade de mapear o endereço que o processo quer ler para o endereço em que aquela memória realmente está. Isso dá ao sistema diversas oportunidades de otimização úteis, como colocar páginas não usadas no disco (swap), as resgatando quando forem requeridas, ou aplicar o copy-on-write (CoW) em que dois processos compartilham a mesma página.

Dessa forma o sistema já sabe exatamente qual memória pertence a cada processo. E liberar essa memória é tão simples quanto a marcar como uma página lixo que pode ser reaproveitada em outro processo. Ou seja, para qualquer computador moderno, terminar um processo significa liberar toda a sua memória.

Considerando um programa grande, existes diversos problemas quando você aperta em "fechar". O destrutor de todos os objetos serão executados em sequencia, fazendo com que um monte de memória semimorta seja acessada e tenha que ser lida do disco (caso tenha acontecido algum swap) e causando lentidão visível ao usuário final. Está se gastando a vida útil do HD enquanto se desperdiça o tempo do utilizador, tudo errado. Isso apenas para liberar recursos que já serão liberados de qualquer forma pelo sistema, e de forma mais eficiente (libera páginas em vez de liberar objeto por objeto, e não precisa ler dados do disco).

Já se isso é boa prática, é questionável. O design da orientação a objetos espera que tudo que for construído seja, em algum momento, destruído. Então pode acontecer de haver alguma lógica importante acontecendo no destrutor, como salvar configurações no disco. Nesse caso meramente chamar `exit(0)` pode ser danoso. Outra forma seria ter uma variável global booleana que seja verdadeira quando o processo está prestes a se encerrar e fazer cada destrutor verificar essa variável, pulando liberações desnecessárias de memória. Mas aqui há pouca vantagem porque um monte de memória precisará ser lida de qualquer forma (voltamos ao swap) e a lógica de destruição se complica e fica não trivial.

Uma solução pode ser ter um mecanismo de notificação que envie algum tipo de sinal a todos os objetos que precisem fazer algo mais na terminação do programa. Pode ser uma lista de callbacks por exemplo. Essa é provavelmente a maneira mais eficiente que não quebra completamente a estrutura orientada a objetos.

O grande problema é que ferramentas que detectam leak vão acusar um monte de problemas no seu programa. Daí é interessante ter dois caminhos de terminação, um desalocando tudo (para debug) e outro indo direto ao `exit(0)`. Os dois devem ser igualmente testados, claro. Mas o segundo não precisa passar pelo leak detector.

Mas se lembre que existem outros recursos que não a memória. Os mecanismos de comunicação inter-processual do System V (disponível em alguns *nix, incluindo o linux), por exemplo, são permanentes e sobrevivem a terminação do processo by-design. Para eles é essencial liberar.

Toda essa discussão só é válida para linguagens onde você programador faz o manejo da memória. Para linguagens com coletor de lixo geralmente não haverá muita escolha.